# Arduino CC3000 with pin 2

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, irq

I'm having problem with the library Adafruit_CC3000 when using the IRQ on pin 2. If I change to 3, everything works fine, but I need the pin 3 free to use on a IR emission using the library IRremote.
I'm using a CC3000 board on top of a Arduino UNO.
Someone already resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is about six months old, but since there were no responses I thought I'd give it a shot.

I've had no problems using IRQ on the Arduino digital 2 pin.  In fact, the AdaFruit connectivity examples use pin 2 as the default.

Assuming you're using pin 2, the code to define the IRQ should look like this:

```
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ 2
```